# Intent to simulate google now voice command with query

Tags: android, android-intent, google-now

I am trying to use the `googlequicksearchbox` to do some actions directly, without the click button confirmation...

for example:

When I click at the mic of Google Now and say "Me acorde às 9:00" (Wake-up me at 9)... Google now makes an alarm for 9 without needing confirmation. Like this:

[image: [1]]

But if I use this intent:

```
    String query = "Me acorde às 9:00";

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    startActivity(intent);
```

to start googlequicksearchbox with the same text that was recognized, Google Now makes the alarm, but now requires confirmation click at the blue button (reminders, etc, also requires). Like that Screenshot >> [Screenshot alarm require confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOH2R.jpg)

Someone knows some way of make the intent start google search with a query and not requires the click confirmation? like "simulate a google now voice command"??

P.S1.: I am using my own voice recognition inside of my app for other purposes, and I am trying to make the Google Now interpret the voice for just some commands... So, unfortunately, I can't execute the google now voice recog...

P.S2.: I don't know how to interpret the voice (get the hour, minutes, etc.) and make the alarm by the direct intent... then, use the google now to interpret is the best option for me.